# MS linq to sql generator - sequention contains more than one element

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I want use it like

```
@foreach (StepArticles obj in data)
{
    @obj.ArticlesDescriptions.Desc
}
```

I have problem with this method

```
return this._StepArticles.Entity;
```

throwing exception: System.InvalidOperationException:sequention contains more than one element

normally iam using association with Id and all working on both OneToOne || OneToMany, but in this case i need to use association with Article-Artikl (varchar)

i think problem will be somewhere so i am trying to ask you... ty a lot :)

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="StepArticles_ArticlesDescriptions", Storage="_StepArticles", ThisKey="Artikl", OtherKey="Article", IsForeignKey=true)]
    public StepArticles StepArticles
    {
        get
        {
            return this._StepArticles.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            StepArticles previousValue = this._StepArticles.Entity;
            if (((previousValue != value) 
                        || (this._StepArticles.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                if ((previousValue != null))
                {
                    this._StepArticles.Entity = null;
                    previousValue.ArticlesDescriptions = null;
                }
                this._StepArticles.Entity = value;
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    value.ArticlesDescriptions = this;
                    this._Artikl = value.Article;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._Artikl = default(string);
                }
                this.SendPropertyChanged("StepArticles");
            }
        }
    }
```

cardinality is set to onetoone

[image]

EDIT ->
So actualy problem is not on side of c# or linq, in view i serialize that object to json JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stepArticles);
so if i delete that all working (but i need that json :))

error:
{"Self referencing loop detected for property 'StepArticles' with type 'Models.StepArticles'. Path '[0].ArticlesDescriptions'."}

Comment: Post the *actual* error text, returned by `Exception.ToString()`. The text `sequention contains more than one element` isn't a .NET exception message. The full text contains inner exceptions and the call stack that points to the actual method that raised the exception. Most likely you used [Single](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.8) on an IQueryable or IEnumerable and got an exception complaining that there are more than one results

Comment: edited  EDIT -> problem is actuali in serializing object but ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, not working

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
return this._StepArticles.Entity;
```

with:

```
return this._StepArticles;
```

Comment: System.Data.Linq.EntityRef <Models.StepArticles> cannot be implicitly converted to Models.StepArticles